# Impossible to turn off PHP safe_mode?

Tags: php, drupal, centos, plesk, safe-mode

I can't upload images in Drupal 7 since I have moved it to a new server: php safe mode was on. So in php.ini I set `safe_mode = Off` (through ssh, I have CentOS).

`phpinfo()` shows that safe_mode is off for master, but on local. I do have a Plesk panel, so I checked there: `safe_mode` was enabled for the domain. I disabled it.

My problem: `safe_mode` is still turned on locally according to `phpinfo()`. What other ways do you know to turn off `safe_mode`? What can be wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you restart the webserver? If it's an apache you'll need to do so for it to reread the config file

Comment: You may aso be able to do an [`.htaccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) and specify to disable safe mode.

Comment: Make sure you're changing the right .ini file as well. PHP tends to have at least two of them (one for web-based, one for command-line), and some distros set up even more for various purposes. You can change it in one spot only to have it overridden elsewhere.

Comment: @Marc B I checked which one I should edit
@Brad Christie Turning off safe mode in .htaccess worked by the way, but I suppose this is not the most clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your httpd.conf and vhost files for...

```
php_admin_flag safe_mode on
```

This flag overrides the setting in your php.ini file. Change it to...

```
php_admin_flag safe_mode off
```

...and restart apache.

EDIT:
Also check the /etc/httpd/conf.d/zz_psa_httpd.conf for that directive.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do first is to edit the main php.ini that overrides all php.ini in domains.

Go to

```
/etc/php.ini
```

and set safe_mode off.

Then restart your web server. You may now set safe_mode on to certain domains using their own php.ini.

Hope this helps.